# Ragged Diamonds

Tags: matrix, algorithm, expression-construction

```
diamond[n_Integer] := 
 Table[1, {#}] & /@ (Range[n]~ Join~Range[n - 1, 1, -1])

diamond[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

How could a more functional, "tablefree", solution look like?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the nice comments and answers so far :)

But I'm looking for a `1-2-3-4-3-2-1` or `1-2-3-4-5-4-3-2-1` sequence which `DiamondMatrix` doesn't seem to offer.

Comment: @Öskå Thanks, but it's not "ragged", but filled with zeroes

Comment: @eldo I believe number of roms should equal 2n-1. most of answerer did not consider this issue.

Comment: @Algohi You posted an answer approx 20 minutes ago which gave what I expected. Why did you delete it? Please repost!

Comment: `DeleteCases[0] /@ DiamondMatrix[10]` ?

Comment: @eldo, I was having some problems with pc and then kguler did something similar and I did not want to repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much to add to the existing answers except that my favorite method to convert lists of natural numbers to all ones is `x^0` therefore:

```
f[n_] := Range[n - Abs @ Range[1-n, n-1]]^0
```

Also I don't believe anyone has yet used `Diagonal`:

```
f2[n_] := With[{m = BoxMatrix[(n - 1)/2]}, Array[m ~Diagonal~ # &, 2 n - 1, 1 - n]]
```

Comment: Your first solution clearly shows why everybody (including myself) should respect the 48-hours-rule before accepting :)

Comment: @eldo Not that I expect you to but you *can* change the Accept if you wish.  I agree however that it's best not to Accept too quickly as I believe it reduces interest in your Question.

Comment: My "mathematical conscience" tells me that I must change the acceptance because of your first solution.

Comment: @eldo Well, thank you. :-)

Comment: Since in this case there are no negative numbers, I would use `UnitStep` to get the `ones`

Comment: @RunnyKine And use *all* those extra characters?  I think not.  ;^)  Honestly `UnitStep` is probably better but since I didn't get to answer early I wasn't trying to write a "canonical" answer but merely have fun with it, which typically means terse.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I figured you were going for terse :)

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm a little bit late to the party but here's a way to generate the ragged diamond using `DiamondMatrix` directly:

```
(* Generate double diamond surrounded by zeros using DiamondMatrix*)
diamondWithin = DiamondMatrix[{4, 5}, {9, 10}];
(* Trim the zeros and resulting empty lists (if any) *)
trimZero = diamondWithin //. {0 :> Sequence[], {} :> Sequence[]};
(* Half the number of 1's in each row *)
goalDiamond = trimZero /. {x__, x__} :> {x};

(* Display *)
{diamondWithin // MatrixForm[# /. {1 :> Style[1, Red]}] &, 
  MatrixForm@trimZero, MatrixForm@goalDiamond} // 
 TableForm[{#}, 
   TableHeadings -> { 
     None, {"diamondWithin", "trimZero", "goalDiamond"}}, 
   TableAlignments -> Center] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### One-liner

```
DiamondMatrix[{4, 5}, {9, 10}] //.
{0 :> Sequence[], {} :> Sequence[]} /.
{x__, x__} :> {x} // MatrixForm
```

---

### A note about `DiamondMatrix`

I found the documentation of this function very vague. The only useful thing I could find was the last example where the function was used like so: `DiamondMatrix[{a, b}, {c, d}]`. After playing around with changing the values of these variables, it seems to me that changing `a` and `b` will affect the height and width (in that order) of the inner diamond, while changing `c` and `d` will change the height and width of the entire matrix that contains the diamond.

I'd built a `Manipulate` to experiment with using the function to create the desired matrix. Note that an odd-width/height matrix will contain only odd-width/height diamond (try it out and you'll see). In this case, the **double diamond** has a width of 10 (even) and height of 9 (odd). Compare these dimensions to just 5 and 9 in the original diamond.

Therefore, I will choose a large matrix with odd height and even width, say 17 x 14, by changing `c` and `d`. I then changed `a` and `b` to get the desired dimension of the inner double diamond (9 x 10; note that 9 and 17 are both odd, while 10 and 14 both even).

After that you can choose to resize the overall matrix down to a smaller size by lowering `c` and `d` (but it really doesn't matter since post-processing will remove anything surrounding the diamond anyway).

Lastly, note that previous answers that involved `DiamondMatrix` did not generate truly "ragged" diamonds, but rather 1, 3, 5, and so on, diamonds.

```
Manipulate[Module[{m, displaym, diamond, mh, mw, dh, dw},
  m = DiamondMatrix[{a, b}, {c, d}];
  displaym = 
   m /. {1 :> Style[1, Red], 0 :> Style[0, Lighter[Gray, 0.7]]};
  diamond = DeleteCases[m, 0, {2}] // DeleteCases[#, {}, {1}] &;
  {mh, mw} = Dimensions@m;
  {dh, dw} = {Length@diamond, Max[Length /@ diamond]};
  
  (* Evaluate mExtract in another cell after you're done manipulating to get the matrix*)
  mExtract = m;
  
  (* Display *)
  {{Style[
      "DiamondMatrix[" <> ToString@{a, b} <> ", " <> ToString@{c, d} <>
        "]", Blue], SpanFromLeft},
    {Style["Diamond:", Red], 
     Grid@Transpose@{Style[#, Red] & /@ {"Height", "Width"}, 
        Style[#, Red] & /@ {dh, dw}}, "Matrix:", 
     Grid@Transpose@{{"Height", "Width"}, {mh, mw}}},
    {MatrixForm@displaym, SpanFromLeft}} // 
   Grid[#, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
     Dividers -> {{2 -> False, 4 -> False}, Automatic}] &],
 
 {{a, 5}, 1, 10, 1}, {{b, 5}, 1, 10, 1}, {{c, 10}, 1, 20, 1}, {{d, 10}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Another way to use `DiamondMatrix`

The diamond matrices in @Szabolcs and @paw's answers generate 1,3,5-diamonds and not 1,2,3-diamond like you wanted. However, a little modification of that matrix will generate the desired diamond.

This is done by observing that a row in a 1,3,5-diamond (let's say the row of length 5) differs from the corresponding row in a 1,2,3-diamond (that means the row of length 3) by half of `Length[row in 1,3,5-diamond] - 1`. In other words, `1 + 2 = 3`, but `1 + 2(2) = 5`.

```
diamond135 = DeleteCases[DiamondMatrix[4], 0, {2}];
diamond135 // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
diamond123 = diamond135 /. x : {1 ..} :> ConstantArray[1, Length@x - (Length@x - 1)/2];
diamond123 // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### One-liner

```
DiamondMatrix[4] /. {0 :> Sequence[]} /.
  x : {1 ..} :> ConstantArray[1, Length@x - (Length@x - 1)/2] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not only fun playing with but also instructive :)

Comment: Thanks! Glad you liked it. I added to my answer another way of using `DiamondMatrix`.

Answer (score 5):

Defining a helper function for tidiness:

```
diamondcounts[n_] := Range[n] ~Join~ Range[n - 1, 1, -1]
```

You could use `ConstantArray` and `Map`

```
ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ diamondcounts[n]
```

But personally I think `Table` is a rather nice choice here:

```
Table[1, {i, diamondcounts[n]}, {i}]
```

Comment: I like `Table[1, {i, diamondcounts[n]}, {i}]`. But why does it function? The `i` is nowhere defined, is it?

Comment: @eldo, `i` is just the iterator variable. In the outer loop it acquires values from `diamondcounts[n]` and then the inner loop runs `i` times.

Answer (score 5):

Using `ArrayPad` to reflect a pyramid matrix:

```
diamond[n_] := ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ Range[n], {{0, n - 1}}, "Reflected"]
diamond[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: +1 Clever use of `ArrayPad`

Answer (score 5):

Here are two different methods based on `Array`:

```
diamond[n_] := With[{a = ConstantArray[1, #] &}, Array[a, n]~ Join ~Reverse@Array[a, n - 1]]
```

OR

```
diamond[n_]:= Array[Array[1 &, #] &, {n}] ~ Join ~ Reverse[Array[Array[1 &, #] &, {n-1}]]

diamond[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I get with `diamond[n_] := 
 Array[ConstantArray[1, #] &, n]~Join~
  Reverse@Array[ConstantArray[1, #] &, n - 1]` an error message: "SetDelayed::write: Tag Function in ((ConstantArray[1,#1]&)/@Join[Range[t],{#1+1},Reverse[Range[#1]]]&)[n_] is Protected."

Comment: @eldo, I don't know why you would get that. It works fine for me. Maybe start a new kernel.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. A little bit strange though, because before my first attempt I executed `Clear["Global`*"]`

Comment: @eldo. Good, glad it works.

Comment: Since I would like to accept this answer please reformulate: `diamond[n_] := 
 With[{a = ConstantArray[1, #] &}, 
  Array[a, n]~Join~Reverse@Array[a, n - 1]]`

Comment: @eldo Suggestion added.

Answer (score 4):

```
diamond[n_] := 1 & /@ Range[#] & /@ (Range[n]~Join~Reverse@Range[n - 1]);
```

or

```
diamond[n_] := Array[1 &, n - Abs[#]] & /@ Range[1 - n, n - 1];

diamond[10]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `FoldList` approach:

```
diamond[n_] := Rest@FoldList[ConstantArray[1, #2] &, 0, Range[n]~Join~Range[n - 1, 1, -1]]
```

Then:

```
diamond[6] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Investigating your answers I found some more possibilities:

A helper function

```
PeekRange[n_] := With[{r = Range @ n}, r ~ Join ~ Reverse @ Most @ r]
```

**[`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html):**

```
diamond1[n_] := Partition[ConstantArray[1, n], n, 1, {-1, 1}, {}]
```

**[`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListConvolve.html):**

```
diamond2[n_] := ConstantArray @@@ ListConvolve[{1}, PeekRange @ n, 1, 0, List]
```

**[`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayReshape.html):**

```
diamond3[n_] := Map[Flatten[ArrayReshape[ConstantArray[1, n], {#, 1}]] &, PeekRange @ n]
```

**[`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html):**

```
diamond4[n_] := 
 Map[First, #]~Join~Rest@Map[Last, #] &[
  ReplaceList[ConstantArray[1, n + 1], {x__, y__} :> {{x}, {y}}]]
```

All give with `n = 5`

[image]

Comment: @Öska Thanks, will remember to give links in the future :)

Comment: It's just a good thing to give links while enumerating the functions IMO :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = Composition[Sign, Range, Range];
bar = Composition[Reverse, Most, foo];
dmnd0 = Join @@ Through[{foo, bar}[#]] &;

dmnd1 = With[{m = Unitize @ Range[Range[#]]}, Join @@ {m, Reverse @ Most @ m}] &
(* or Sign instead of Unitize *)

dmnd2 = With[{r = Join[Range[0, #-1], Range[#-2, 0, -1]]}, ArrayPad[{1}, {0, #}, 1]& /@ r] &

dmnd3 = Join @@ {#, Reverse[Most@#]} &@NestList[Append[#1, 1] &, {1}, # - 1] &

dmnd4 = Join @@{Reverse[Rest@#], #} &@ NestList[Drop[#, 1] &, Array[1 &, {#}], # - 1] &

dmnd0[5] //MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
dmnd0[5] == dmnd1[5] == dmnd2[5] == dmnd3[5] == dmnd4[5]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways possible

```
diamond = Function[ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ Join[Range@t, {# + 1}, Reverse@Range@#] // MatrixForm]
diamond@5
```

more or less complicate, with SparseArray

```
diamond = 
 Function[SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> 1, {#, #}]~Join~
      Reverse@SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> 1, {#, #}] // Normal //
     ReplaceAll[#, 0 -> Sequence[]] & // 
   Column[#, Alignment -> Center] &]

diamond@5
```

or just pure "1"

```
diamond = 
 Function[Array[Row@Array[" 1 " &, #] &, {# + 1}]~Join~
    Reverse@Array[Row@Array[" 1 " &, #] &, {#}] // 
   Column[#, Alignment -> Center] &]
diamond@5
```

without function

```
a = Array[1 &, #] &;
Array[a, {6}]~Join~ Reverse@Array[a, {5}] // MatrixForm
Array[a, {6}]~Join~ Reverse@Array[a, {5}] // 
 Column[#, Alignment -> Center] &
```

or a squareDiamond (did it also)

```
DiamondMatrix@10 /. (0 -> Sequence[]) // MatrixForm
```

and more and more ...

[image: diamondMatrix]

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DeleteCases[#, 0] & /@ DiamondMatrix[10]
```

it's about 3 times as fast then what Öska suggested.